# Android: scrollable textview for very large textfile

Tags: android, textview

I have some very large text files, about several mega bytes to be shown. Basically, I don't want to load one after loading the whole text, because this could be very slow and causing memory issues. What I want to do is loading some part of the it, such several kilos and when scrolling, the textview could dynamically expand to show new text. But this has some challenges to me...
Has anyone done this before? Pls give some hints.

Comment: Did you consider using WebView instead of TextView?

Comment: yes, something like Webview, but Webview lost the position information each time I open the file..And I want to do more control for displaying the text file